# Click event on <a> tag doesn't work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, anchor, jquery-events

I'm trying to alter a click event on my `<a>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>JQuery test</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('doc. ready');
    
                $('#id_product_quick').on('click', function (e) {
                    alert('click');
    
                    e.preventDefault();
    
                    loading();
    
                })
    
            });

       </script>

    </head>

    <body>
       <a id="#id_product_quick" class="col-md-4" href="/scr/quick/3/"><img style="width: 200px" src="/static/img/icons/Button.png"></a>

    </body>

</html>
```

The JavaScript loads and alerts `$(document).ready` with success, but when I click on the `<a>` tag, I'm redirected to the original href when I want to escape the default action or alert 'click'.

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `#` from Id attribute of HTML.

```
<a id="id_product_quick" class="col-md-4" href="/scr/quick/3/"><img style="width: 200px" src="/static/img/icons/Button.png"> </a>
```

or, Escape meta-character `#` with `\\` from selector while attaching event handler

```
$('#\\#id_product_quick').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('click');
    e.preventDefault();
    loading();
})
```

See [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.